# dialogflow - private agent and user authentication

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Is it possible to build and deploy an agent available only for some users , like for example a company, or limiting access ?

Answer (score -2):

It depends on exactly what your needs are.

While not exactly what you are looking for, you can deploy an Action to [Alpha](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments) test status. This lets you make it available to up to 20 users without going through the review process.

Additionally, you can deploy it to up to 200 users if you deploy to Beta. However, this still will require a review by the Action review team.

If you need more than this (and probably a wise idea even in other use cases), you'll need to use [Google Sign in for Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) or other identity methods to get the identity of the user and then determine if this is an authorized user as part of your Action. This will require review by the Action review team.